# Error 403: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server with apache, mod-wsgi and django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wampserver, http-status-code-403

I am new in django and apache. I want to publish my django website by apache and mod-wsgi.
when I start httpd.exe, I recieve 403 forbidden error in my browser.
my apache config is here

```
LoadFile "c:/users/zharf/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3/envs/django/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/zharf/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/zharf/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3/envs/django"



Alias /static/ /D:/user/JarfaSys/static/
<Directory D:/user/JarfaSys/static/>
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /D:/user/JarfaSys/
WSGIPassAuthorization On



<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot D:/user/JarfaSys
    Alias /favicon.ico D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/favicon.ico
    Alias / /D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/wsgi.py

    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/Users/zharf/TibiFiles/host.key
    SSLCertificateFile  C:/Users/zharf/TibiFiles/host.cert
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    <Directory D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>             

</VirtualHost>


WSGIScriptAlias / /D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /D:/user/JarfaSys/
WSGIPassAuthorization On


<Directory D:/user/JarfaSys/JarfaSys/>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

wsgi.py is :

```
import os
import sys

path = "D:/Ghanbari/JarfaSys/JarfaSys"
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/.python-eggs'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "JarfaSys.settings")

#print os.getenv("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")
#print os.getenv("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

error log file is here

```
[Fri Aug 23 16:29:26.827875 2019] [core:error] [pid 10784:tid 1092] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50025] AH00036: access to / failed (filesystem path 'C:/D:')
[Fri Aug 23 16:29:26.848875 2019] [core:error] [pid 10784:tid 1092] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50025] AH00036: access to /favicon.ico failed (filesystem path 'C:/D:'), referer: http://localhost/
```

Apache service user has access to my app directory.
I study many similar questions but the problem is not solved. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of project setup in apache. You vhosts file has a few errors

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost

    ErrorLog "logs/logname-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/logname-access.log" common

    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\workspace\your_project_path\wsgi.py"
    Alias /static/ C:/workspace/static/

    <Directory C:\your_project_path>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Remove the `/` Before the `D:/...` use the above as pattern.

and an example of a wsgi.py

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

activate_env = r"C:\your_virtual_environment_path\Scripts\activate_this.py"
with open(activate_env) as f:
    exec(f.read(), {"__file__": activate_env})

from your_main import app as application
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I replaced your configuration code and the problem was resolved